# searching for non english word in a file python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to solve "simple" problem in python (2.7).
suppose that i have two files:

key.txt - which have a key to search for.
content.txt - which has a web content (html file)

both files saved in utf-8.
content.txt is mixed file, which means it contains non english characters (web html file)

i am trying to check if the key in key.txt file found in the content or not.
tried comparing the files as binary (bytes) didn't work, also tried decoding didn't work.

i would also appreciate any help on how can i search for regex which is mixed (my pattern built from english and non-english characters)

Comment: did you try:`if open("key.txt","rb").read() in open("context.txt","rb").read():` ... its not very clear from your post what you are trying to do, nor what you have tried

Comment: yes it didn't work.
what i am trying is very simple, i am searching for a pattern in a webpage, but this pattern isn't english only.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the python interpreter know that you are using utf-8 encoding by 
adding this statement at the beginning :

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Then you can use **u'yourString'** to indicate that string is a unicode string.

Sample code :

```
text = u'someString'
keyString = u'someKey'
f = re.findall(keyString, text)
```

You may need to use encode('utf-8') method on the string while performing some other operation on those strings